# Проблемы с BitLocker

Tags: windows

Хотел зашифровать диск C: с помощью Bitlocker (windows 10) и наткнулся на неприятную ситуацию.

Окно ошибки после перезапуска ОС:
[image: Окно ошибки после перезапуска ОС]

Проверка модуля TPM отключена + флешка в порядке (проверял на нескольких), но есть нюанс: на жёстком диске 2 ОС: windows 7 и windows 10 виртуальный диск с диска D:, после неудачной попытки зашифровать диск C: windows 10 я попробовал повторить то же самое с диском C: windowc 7, которая установлена на разбитый том ЖД, а не на виртуальный диск, нарвался на точно такую же ошибку, но без упоминания о модуле TVP.

Окно ошибки после перезапуска основной ОС:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть догадка, что это происходит из-за непонимания BIOS к какой OC просматривать ключ с флешки, потому что пользователь ещё не выбрал ОС в окне загрузки, поэтому шифрование системного диска определённой ОС невозможно при наличии нескольких ОС на ЖД. Или я ошибаюсь?